# Travelling to Schengen with Romania residence permit

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, indonesian-citizens

I'm an Indonesian citizen, going to Romania for about 4 months to take part in a student exchange from Erasmus. Because I'm staying for more than 90 days, I need to apply for a residence permit.

If I get this residence permit, do I still need to apply for a Schengen visa if I want to go around Europe?

This is my first time coming to Europe.

Answer (score 2):

A Romanian residence permit does **not** exempt you from a Schengen visa.

Thus, to visit the Schengen Area, you still need one.

Comment: @Deo If this answers your question, please accept it by upvoting and pressing the button below the down arrow